# Datagridview keyboard cursor to specific cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I searched about setting cursor to focus to specific cell and I found the following

```
        DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Add(15); // load empty rows for display 
        DGV_INVOICE.CurrentCell = DGV_INVOICE.Rows[0].Cells[1];
        DGV_INVOICE.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
        DGV_INVOICE.BeginEdit(true);
```

I have managed the tab order option and set it to strat with the `datagridview`
but that wont allow me to start typing directly the keyboard cursor go to first `textbox` regardless the tab order I have set before

I want to know how to start typing directly at specific cell of `datagridview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was very simple and surprised me !!
all I have to do is just to remove the `BeginEdit` i don't know why but that is 
solve my problem .. if someone has an explication it will be grate

```
        DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Add(15);
        DGV_INVOICE.CurrentCell = DGV_INVOICE.Rows[0].Cells[1];
        DGV_INVOICE.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
        //DGV_INVOICE.BeginEdit(true); /// remove that part of code to problem
```